# cURL GET request ignoring my data input

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

I am trying to use PHP and cURL to get information about a specific IP in a Cloudflare firewall.

But the following request always returns **all** IPs that are set in the firewall.

Is it not possible to use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with a GET request?

How do I correctly build a GET request with PHP and cURL that has an array with data to request?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->settings['cloudflare_rules_url'] );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );

$headers = [
    'X-Auth-Email: ' . $this->settings['x_auth_email'],
    'X-Auth-Key: ' . $this->settings['x_auth_key'],
    'Content-Type: application/json',
];

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

$search_filter = array(
    'configuration_target' => 'ip', 
    'configuration_value' => '123.123.123.123',

);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $search_filter ) );

$result = curl_exec( $ch );

curl_close( $ch );

error_log( print_r( json_decode( $result, true ), true ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, but I'm not sure if this is the moste elegant way.

The solution would be to url-encode the query array parameters into the CURLOPT_URL.

```
$search_filter = array(
    'configuration_target' => 'ip', 
    'configuration_value' => '123.123.123.123',

);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->settings['cloudflare_rules_url'] . '/?' . http_build_query( $search_filter ));
```

Comment: Yes You must add data to url if method GET

Comment: @Matx132 that is not true. GET requests can have request bodies, just like POST requests. its just uncommon. to prove this, run `curl -v -X GET --data test=foo example.org` and see, what do you get? a GET request with a request body, and content-length, just like a POST request :)

Comment: @hanshenrik Why is it then not working in my example above? Is it because I use to build the request with PHP?